# Call a prestashop module with ajax

Tags: ajax, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a PrestaShop module called 'MyMenu' and I want call this menu with an AJAX call.
My module is displayed in the `hookFooter()` method:

```
public function hookFooter()
{
    $display = $this->display(__FILE__, 'megamenu.tpl', $smartyCacheId);
    Tools::restoreCacheSettings();
    return  $display;
}
```

I want display with this script:

```
<div class="load_menu"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "../modules/MyMenu.php",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $('.load_menu').html(data);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of prestashop? 1.6?

Comment: Version 1.7.0.2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a new file at the module root, you can create a file "ajax.php"

```
require_once(MODULE_DIR.'MyMenu/mymenu.php');
if(Tools::getValue('token') !=
$mymenu = Module::getInstanceByName('mymenu');
$menu = $mymenu->hookFooter();
die($menu);
```

In your js, at the root of your module

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "./ajax.php",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('.load_menu').html(data);
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is an error of PHP syntax (require_one ...) and this does not respect Prestashop's Standards.

Comment: he just wrong to write, it is obviously require_once() function

Comment: @MattLoye You should add this lines to your answer to be correct, you followed the Pestashop ajax controller creation but you didn't answer to the question, 
the main answer is here 
require_once(MODULE_DIR.'MyMenu/mymenu.php');
$mymenu = Module::getInstanceByName('mymenu');
$menu = $mymenu->hookFooter();

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to do it via a front controller linked to your module.
You can call the url like this :

```
$link->getModuleLink('modulename','controller', $parameters);
// Parameters is an optionnal array, it can be empty
```

And for the controller, place a file like this ./modules/modulename/controllers/front/ajax.php with this kind of content :

```
class ModuleNameAjaxModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
public function initContent()
{

    $response = array('status' => false);

    require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'modulename/modulename.php';

    $module = new ModuleName;

    if (Tools::isSubmit('action')) {
        $context = Context::getContext();

        $cart = $context->cart;

        switch (Tools::getValue('action')) {

            case 'actionname':


                $response = array('status' => true);

                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    // Classic json response
    $json = Tools::jsonEncode($response);
    $this->ajaxDie($json);

    // For displaying like any other use this method to assign and display your template placed in modules/modulename/views/template/front/...
    // $this->context->smarty->assign(array('var1'=>'value1'));
    // $this->setTemplate('template.tpl');

    // For sending a template in ajax use this method
    // $this->context->smarty->fetch('template.tpl');

}
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. Always use controllers, also instead of `echo Tools::jsonEncode($response); die;` you can use `$this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode($response))` since that method also executes two hooks before ajax output in case of any modules using the hooks.

Comment: True and maybe encapsulate jsonEncode before.
I'm gonna edit my answer.

Comment: I do not understand how to use this method, to call a menu that should display without calling.. why " if (Tools::isSubmit('action')) "?

Comment: You can remove this part, it was to make an ajax handling method with some flexibility ...
You should take a loot at a part of classes in Prestashop files.

Comment: Also, you should check https://validator.prestashop.com, there is a Module Generator, it will be easier for you to understand how to make a module in Prestashop that way.

Comment: @MattLoye the require_once should be called before class declaration, you didn't get the content of a hook module to diplay it on success ajax call, so you have only used a controller to do an ajax call that do nothing, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass the url by the module, the js snippet should be like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        url : baseDir + 'modules/yourmodulename/yourfile.php',
        data: {
            token : token
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('.load-menu').html(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Where `yourmodulename` is the name of your module and `yourfile.php` is the code where you retrieve the menu.

Don't forget to add to your data the token, it's to prevent a CSFR attack, obviously you have to check the token in your server side script as well.