# Submit a form in the background with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, prestashop

I have the following problem, I am using Prestashop and I need a form to make a submit in the background, I have investigated and I found a way to do it with ajax but I need the url and data parameter that I do not know how to get them since the form is this.

As you can see, the form has no action and the data is not clearly visible, this would be the way I have in mind to do it with ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#makePdfCatalogue").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $("#makePdfCatalogue").serialize(); //this way i cant get the data
    console.log(dataString);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "", //action doenst appear 
      data: dataString,
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log('working: ' + msg);
      },
      error: function(msg) {
        //console.log('not working ' + msg);
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="makePdfCatalogue" name="makePdfCatalogue" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Categorías</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="name">{l s="Selecciona la categoría/s que deseas exportar" mod="custompdfexport"}</label> {$categories_tree}
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos empresa</legend>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="name">Nombre Empresa</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder={l s="Nombre Empresa..." mod="custompdfexport" } class="form-control" id="name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="contact">Datos contacto</label>
              <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder={l s="Datos Contacto..." mod="custompdfexport" } class="form-control" id="contact">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="logo">Logo empresa</label>
              <input type="file" name="logo" placeholder={l s="logo Empresa..." mod="custompdfexport" } class="form-control" id="logo">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Opciones</legend>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="form-password">{l s="Diseño" mod="custompdfexport"}</label>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="format" class="form-control" value="2" id="format-2"><label for="format-2">{l s="2 columnas" mod="custompdfexport"}</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="format" class="form-control" value="3" id="format-3"><label for="format-3">{l s="3 columnas" mod="custompdfexport"}</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="radio" name="format" class="form-control" value="4" id="format-4"><label for="format-4">{l s="4 columnas" mod="custompdfexport"}</label>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="form-password">Opciones</label>
              <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" class="form-control" id="opt-wt" value="wt"><label for="opt-wt">{l s="Mostrar Precios con Iva" mod="custompdfexport"}</label></div>
              <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" class="form-control" id="opt-wot" value="wot"><label for="opt-wot"> {l s="Mostrar Precios sin Iva" mod="custompdfexport"}</label></div>
              <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" class="form-control" id="opt-ref" value="reference"><label for="opt-ref">{l s="Mostrar referencia" mod="custompdfexport"}</label></div>
              <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" class="form-control" id="opt-link" value="link"><label for="opt-link">{l s="Enlazar productos con web" mod="custompdfexport"}</label></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="revenue">Margen comercial (%)</label>
              <input type="text" name="revenue" placeholder={l s="Margen comercial..." mod="custompdfexport" } class="form-control" id="revenue" style="width: 100px;">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="" for="revenue">Descuento (%)</label>
              <input type="text" name="reduction" placeholder={l s="Descuento..." mod="custompdfexport" } class="form-control" id="reduction" style="width: 100px;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="" for="form-password">Ordenar</label>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="radio" name="order" class="form-control" id="order-asc" value="price_asc"><label for="order-asc">{l s="Por precio de Menor a Mayor" mod="custompdfexport"}</label></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="radio" name="order" class="form-control" id="order-desc" value="price_desc"><label for="order-desc">{l s="Por precio de Mayor a Menor" mod="custompdfexport"}</label></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="" for="form-password">Stock</label>
            <div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" name="stock" class="form-control" id="stock" value="stock"><label for="stock">{l s="Seleccionar sólo artículos con stock"}</label></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$token|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
      <input type="submit" name="submitMakePdfCatalogue" id="submitMakePdfCatalogue" value="{l s='Generar' mod='custompdfexport'}" class="exclusive" />

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

any suggestion of how to get those parameters...

Comment: The `serialize()` call is working correctly - as you can see from the `console.log()` line I edited in to your question. For what reason do you believe the values are not being read? I would assume this is more of a server side issue, as such I'd suggest staring your debugging efforts there.

Comment: As an aside I would suggest wrapping your `placeholder` attribute values in quotes, as you can see from the HTML syntax highlighting that there's some syntax issues there.

Comment: how can you submit form without knowing where to submit form, or lets say action attribute for form?

Comment: I think it is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925427/call-a-prestashop-module-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the data problem and I also know that the action is catalogue.php but I don't know how to locate it with the url since it is inside a prestashop module. I tried something like that but it gave me an error 500 that is, it is not the correct path

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
              $("#makePdfCatalogue").submit(function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var dataString = $("#makePdfCatalogue").serialize(); //solved
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                      url: baseDir + 'modules/custompdfexport/controllers/front/catalogue.php',//is not the correct url
                      data: dataString,
                      success: function(msg) {

                          console.log('working: '+msg);
                      },
                      error: function(msg) {

                          console.log('not working '+msg);
                      }
                  });
              })
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get a link to your controller:

```
Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink('custompdfexport', 'catalogue');
```

In your case you are calling controller via AJAX so you need pass the `ajax` parameter in url like this:

```
Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink('custompdfexport', 'catalogue', array('ajax' => true));
```

If you have URL rewriting enabled your URL will look something like:

> http://<shop_domain>/en/module/custompdfexport/catalogue?ajax=true

[Source](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/)